# jenkins - chaining dropdowns in jelly conig file

Tags: plugins, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

My buildwrapper plugin needs 2 dropdowns, the 2nd depending on the value selected in the 1st.
The options for both dropdowns are dynamic /computed in code/
I can't figure out how to "refresh" the options in the 2nd dropdown from the Java class, any clues?

Thanks,

Comment: This might help, its adding JQuery and JQuery-UI into plugins https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jenkinsci-dev/HrpHpqF8Y_I/LnM2JdLZ7aUJ